# Is it safe to use raw emojis in PHP source code?

Tags: php, emoji

Example :

```
$fire = '';
```

I know PHP 5+ supports this functionality natively but is it best practice or should I be storing them using their codepoints instead and if so, why?

Comment: I don't think this does make any difference. Using emoji icons seems much more verbose.

Comment: What do you mean by "using their code points"? Incidentally, `$ = 'fire';` is also valid, but you might annoy people reading the code if you do that...

Comment: Well the codepoint for this emoji is U+1F525. I have no idea how to use it, if it needs to be used at all. Just feels wrong to be pasting graphics directly into source code...

Comment: In PHP 7 you can use `echo "\u{1f525}";` if you want. But I use these emoji's also directly in my code, until now without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your editor and the PHP compiler are concerned, it's all just text, and '' is no different from 'fire' or 'Φωτιά'.

When PHP runs, it will read the bytes in from the file and put them in memory, without caring what they mean. This leads to the most likely problem you'll have: if you save the file in your text editor as UTF-16, and then echo the string to a browser telling it that it's UTF-8, the browser won't show the right thing. But that's easily avoided by making sure your editor always uses UTF-8, and your output headers tell the browser that's what you're using.

If you don't trust your editor to do that, and you're running PHP7, you could write it in the escaped notation `"\u{1f525}"`, but when it runs, the same bytes will end up in memory.

You might have similar problems if you send the text elsewhere - to a database, for instance - and that somewhere else doesn't know to handle it as UTF-8. How you write the string in your source file won't make any difference to that, though, that's just a case of making sure everything is configured to match.

Note: you don't actually have to use UTF-8 for this, you could use UTF-16, or some other encoding, as long as you're consistent; but UTF-8 is by far the most common these days, particularly on the web.

Comment: Great and insightful answer, exactly what I was looking for, thank you!